# Failing Test: Nothing was returned from render. identical test passes, only difference with the failing test is the use of initialEntries

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-router, react-testing-library

I'm trying to test if my routes are working, the first test passes when I test the default "/" route, however the second test does not pass. the only difference is that in the second test the `initialEntries={['/register']}` is introduced, and as a result the second test fails for this reason:

> "Login(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a
> return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null."

I've checked the other questions regarding this but they don't seem to match my particular problem

this is my app.js that contains all the routes

```
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom'
import PrivateRoute from './components/PrivateRoute';
import Login from './components/LoginRegister/Login';
import Dashboard from './components/Dashboard/Dashboard';
import Register from './components/LoginRegister/Register';
import PageNotFound from './components/Pages/PageNotFound';
import Header from './components/LoginRegister/Header';
function App() {

  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="main-container">
          <div className="Route-container">
          <Header/>
              <Switch>
                <PrivateRoute exact path = '/dashboard' component = {Dashboard}></PrivateRoute> 
                <Route exact path = '/' component = {Login} />
                <Route exact path = '/test' component = {Dashboard} />
                <Route exact path = '/register' component = {Register} /> 
                <Route component = {PageNotFound} /> 
              </Switch>
          </div>
        </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is my App.test.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import { MemoryRouter } from 'react-router';
import App from "./App";
import Dashboard from './components/Dashboard/Dashboard'; 
import Header from './components/LoginRegister/Header';
import Login from './components/LoginRegister/Login';
import Register from './components/LoginRegister/Register';
import PageNotFound from './components/Pages/PageNotFound';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';

jest.mock('./components/Dashboard/Dashboard');
jest.mock('./components/LoginRegister/Login');
jest.mock('./components/LoginRegister/Register');
jest.mock('./components/Pages/PageNotFound');
jest.mock('./components/LoginRegister/Header');

describe("App component", () =>{
    it("renders page header and login component on default route", ()=>{
        Header.mockImplementation(()=> <div>HeaderMock</div>);
        Login.mockImplementation(()=> <div>LoginMock</div>);

        render(
          <MemoryRouter>
            <App />
          </MemoryRouter>
        );
        
        expect(screen.getByText("HeaderMock")).toBeInTheDocument();
        expect(screen.getByText("LoginMock")).toBeInTheDocument();
    });

    it("Renders page header and Register component on Register route", ()=>{
      Header.mockImplementation(()=> <div>HeaderMock</div>);
      Register.mockImplementation(()=> <div>RegisterMock</div>);

      render(
        <MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/register']}>
            <App />
        </MemoryRouter>
      );
      
      expect(screen.getByText("HeaderMock")).toBeInTheDocument();
      expect(screen.getByText("RegisterMock")).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

This is the Register.js component

```
import React from 'react'
import { useState } from 'react';
import { Link, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

const initialState = {
    credentials: {
    name: '',
    username: '',
    password: ''
  }
}

function Register() {
    const [state, setState] = useState(initialState)
    const history = useHistory()

    function goToLogin () {
        history.push('/')
    }

function handleChange(e) {
    setState({
        credentials: {
            ...state.credentials,
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        }
    })
   }
    return (
        <div className = "main-container">
            
            <div className = "middle-section">
                
                <div className= "login-section">
                
                    <div className = "selection login-flex-item">
                        Already a member? &nbsp;
                        <Link to ='/' className = 'select-logreg'>Login</Link>
                    </div>

                    <form className = 'login-flex-item' onSubmit = {goToLogin}>
                
                        <input className = 'form-item'
                            type = 'text'
                            name = 'name'
                            placeholder = "Enter Name"
                            value = {state.credentials.name}
                            onChange ={handleChange}
                        />
                        <input className = 'form-item'
                            type = 'text'
                            name = 'username'
                            placeholder = "Username"
                            value = {state.credentials.username}
                            onChange ={handleChange}
                        />
                        <input className = 'form-item'
                            type="password"
                            name="password"
                            placeholder = "Password"
                            value={state.credentials.password}
                            onChange={handleChange}
                        />
                        <button className = 'form-item btn'>Sign Up</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Register;
```

and this is the test fail description I am getting any help would be awesome ive been staring at this for hours and cant seem to find a solution.

```
 FAIL  src/App.test.js
  App component
    √ renders page header and login component on default route (33 ms)
    × Renders page header and Register component on Register route (198 ms)

  ● App component › Renders page header and Register component on Register route

    Login(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.

      35 |       Register.mockImplementation(()=> <div>RegisterMock</div>);
      36 |
    > 37 |       render(
         |       ^
      38 |         <MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/register']}>
      39 |             <App />
      40 |         </MemoryRouter>

      at reconcileChildFibers (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:14169:23)
      at reconcileChildren (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:16990:28)
      at mountIndeterminateComponent (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:17890:5)
      at beginWork (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:19049:16)
      at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:3945:14)
      at HTMLUnknownElement.callTheUserObjectsOperation (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/generated/EventListener.js:26:30)
      at innerInvokeEventListeners (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:338:25)
      at invokeEventListeners (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:274:3)
      at HTMLUnknownElementImpl._dispatch (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:221:9)
      at HTMLUnknownElementImpl.dispatchEvent (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:94:17)
      at HTMLUnknownElement.dispatchEvent (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/generated/EventTarget.js:231:34)
      at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:3994:16)
      at invokeGuardedCallback (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:4056:31)
      at beginWork$1 (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:23964:7)
      at performUnitOfWork (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22779:12)
      at workLoopSync (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22707:5)
      at renderRootSync (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22670:7)
      at performSyncWorkOnRoot (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22293:18)
      at scheduleUpdateOnFiber (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21881:7)
      at updateContainer (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:25482:3)
      at node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:26021:7
      at unbatchedUpdates (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22431:12)
      at legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:26020:5)
      at Object.render (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:26103:10)
      at node_modules/@testing-library/react/dist/pure.js:101:25
      at batchedUpdates$1 (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22380:12)
      at act (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-test-utils.development.js:1042:14)
      at render (node_modules/@testing-library/react/dist/pure.js:97:26)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/App.test.js:37:7)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the doc [`<Router>`](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Router):

> The common low-level interface for all router components. Typically apps will use **one of** the high-level routers instead:
>
> - `<BrowserRouter>`
> - `<HashRouter>`
> - `<MemoryRouter>`
> - `<NativeRouter>`
> - `<StaticRouter>`

The issue is `<BrowserRouter>` component is wrapped in `<MemoryRouter>` like this:

```js
<MemoryRouter>
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
     ....
    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>
</MemoryRouter>
```

This will give you the `location` from `<BrowserRouter>`, it will be:

```js
location:  { pathname: '/', search: '', hash: '', state: undefined }
```

You should split the `<Switch>` and its children as an independent component like `Routes`:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

const Login = () => <div>login</div>;
const Register = () => <div>Register</div>;

export const Routes = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  console.log('location: ', location);
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
      <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
    </Switch>
  );
};

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes />
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

So that you can use `Routes` with `<MemoryRouter>` for testing:

```
import React from 'react';
import { MemoryRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';
import { Routes } from './app';

describe('App component', () => {
  it('renders page header and login component on default route', () => {
    render(
      <MemoryRouter>
        <Routes />
      </MemoryRouter>
    );
    expect(screen.getByText('login')).toBeInTheDocument();
  });

  it('Renders page header and Register component on Register route', () => {
    render(
      <MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/register']}>
        <Routes />
      </MemoryRouter>
    );
    expect(screen.getByText('Register')).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

test result:

```
 PASS  examples/70090905/app.test.tsx (8.087 s)
  App component
    ✓ renders page header and login component on default route (45 ms)
    ✓ Renders page header and Register component on Register route (3 ms)

  console.log
    location:  {
      pathname: '/',
      search: '',
      hash: '',
      state: undefined,
      key: 'zlnxcn'
    }

      at Routes (examples/70090905/app.tsx:9:11)

  console.log
    location:  {
      pathname: '/register',
      search: '',
      hash: '',
      state: undefined,
      key: '8z804n'
    }

      at Routes (examples/70090905/app.tsx:9:11)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        8.625 s, estimated 11 s
```

For illustrative and demonstration purposes, I removed unnecessary code.

Package versions:

```json
"react-router-dom": "^5.2.0"
```